# How to convert columns to row sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to convert columns into row in MS Sql.so i tried below code

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('tbl_login_settings') 

         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = 'select  value
     from tbl_login_settings
     unpivot
     (
        value
        for year in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
     ) lab_name'

exec(@query)
```

its working fine but problem is its converting all columns(all rows values) into rows.

i need particular  columns(rows values) into rows

e.g

```
sno/ name/ visible// column name
1  / sam / show
2  / ram / hide // i need to convert this rows like below
3  / mick / show

values// column name
2
ram
hide
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('tbl_login_settings') 

         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = 'select  value
     from tbl_login_settings where sno = 2
     unpivot
     (
        value
        for year in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
     ) lab_name'

exec(@query)
```